# Drawing vector map

Tags: javascript, html, visualization, data-visualization

I was wondering if there was a library that lets me solve my issue. I want to visualize a 'map' of nodes, each connected to the rest through simple coordinates.

So for instance if N1...N6 are such nodes, in text it would look something like this:

```
    N2
    |
N3----N1----N4
    |
    N5----N6
```

So in this example N1 is 'south' of N2 (and N2 is 'north' of N1), etc. I already have the nodes in a MySQL table and I can export them in any way necessary, but I'm not sure how to draw their relationships to make the map interactive.

What's the best way to do this in HTML5/javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't need analysis or care about co-occurance, I want visualization.

Comment: Visualisation can be very broad, d3.js can do a lot, see https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock

Comment: more on d3.js: https://d3js.org/